# How to add multiple jQuery custom widgets to div and later call their methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I have object container `<div id="dObjectContainer" class="dObjectContainer">`
and a widget TreeObject.

```
        $.widget('qs.TreeObject2', {

    options: {
        oID: '0',
        IMGUrl: '../../Content/Images/noIMG.jpg',
        Name: 'Name',
        IsActive: true,
        IsVisible: true

    },
    _create: function () {
        var self = this,
        o = self.options,
        el = self.element;
        el.attr("oID", o.oID);
        el.addClass("dObject");
        el.addClass("ui-widget-content");

        var H1 = $("<h1></h1>").text(o.Name);
        el.append(H1);

        var img = $("<img></img>");
        img.attr("src", o.IMGUrl);
        img.attr("alt", o.Name);
        el.append(img);


    },
    DoHide: function (strName, bActive) {
        var self = this,
        o = self.options;
        if (((o.Name.toUpperCase().indexOf(strName.toUpperCase()) > -1) || (strName == "")) && ((o.IsActive) || (bActive == false))) {
            if (!o.IsVisible) {
                this.element.show();
                o.IsVisible = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (o.IsVisible) {
                this.element.hide();
                o.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }

    },

    destroy: function () {
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);

    }
});
```

I want to add multiple objects from javascript something like this:

```
    $('#dObjectContainer').append($("<div></div>").TreeObject2({ oID: "1", IMGUrl: '../../Content/Images/StoredImages/Categories/images.jpg', Name: "n1", IsActive: true }));
    $('#dObjectContainer').append($("<div></div>").TreeObject2({ oID: "2", Name: "n2",  IsActive: false }));
```

This approach adds two elemets of each object instead of one. - Found reason - for some unknown reson ASP.MVC 3 razor view calls `(function ($) {} (jQuery));` twice. First time it calls only view document.ready - second time layoutpage and view document ready.

For other part - how to access their metods:

```
$('.dObject').TreeObject2("DoHide", strName, bActive);
```

This works in case there is no more elements having class dObject.

Comment: What is TreeObject? What does it do?

Comment: @RichardD At this stage I experimenting with widgets, this particular widget only will be able to hide, if asked to hide all inactive ones.